# Groovy difference between 'any' and 'find' methods

Tags: groovy

In groovy, there are two methods namely `any` and `find` method that can be used in Maps.

Both these methods will "search" for the content that we are interested in (that is, both `any` and `find` method return whether the element is in Map or not, that is they need to search).

But within this search how do they differ?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [`find`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#find%28%29) and [`any`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#any%28%29) Hint: The difference lies with the return type

Answer (score 4):

They actually do different things. `find` returns the actual element that was found whereas `any` produces a bool value. What makes this confusing for you is the groovy truth.

**Any unset (null?) value will resolve to false**

```
def x
assert !x
```

So if you are just checking for *false*, then the returned values from both methods will serve the same purpose, since essentially all objects have an implicit existential boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

```
 (!list.find{predicate}) <> (!list.any{predicate})
```

However :

```
( list.find{predicate}) >< (list.any{predicate})
```

If any does not exist in Groovy API and you want to add this feature to List metClass, any implementation will be :

```
java.util.List.metaClass.any={Closure c-> 
     return delegate.find(c) != null

}
```

## Find is more general than any

Comment: What is the `><` operator? How is it called?

Comment: @Agorreca, `<>` mean "equivalent to", `><` means the opposite of `<>`. These are not actual groovy operators